# Doctrine 2 DQL with nested parameters throws a Invalid PathExpression exception

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm having problems writing a correct DQL for my code (Exception : Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression).
I'll start by sketching the structure of my project.

Every entity inherits from IdentifiableObject that provides every entity with an id

```php
 /**
 * @MappedSuperclass
 */
class IdentifiableObject {
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * getters and setters go here
     */
}
```

Then we have a User object that has a list of "UserProperties"

```php
 /**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends IdentifiableObject {
    /**
     * Other unimportant vars go here
     */

    /**
     * @Column(type="string")
     */
    private $userName;

     /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserProperty", mappedBy="user", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $userProperties = null;

     public function __construct() {
        $this->userProperties = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Getters and setters go here
     */
}
```

The Userproperty has a property (which is basicaly a type saying what kind of userproperty it is) and a value

```php
    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="userProperties")
     */
    class UserProperty extends IdentifiableObject {
        /**
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Property")
         * @JoinColumn(name="propertyID", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $property;

        /**
         * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
         * @JoinColumn(name="userID", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $userValue
    }
```

And finally the Property

```php
    /**
     * @Entity
     * @Table(name="properties")
     */
    class Property extends IdentifiableObject {

        /**
         * @Column(type="string")
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @Column(type="string")
         */
        private $description;

        /**
         * @Column(type="integer")
         */
        private $mandatory = 0;

        /**
         * @OneToOne(targetEntity="PropertyType")
         * @JoinColumn(name="type", referencedColumnName="id")
         */
        private $type;
}
```

What i would like to do is get all Users that have a Userproperty corresponding to a certain Property.
My attempt was :

```
$queryUserId = "SELECT userprop.user FROM UserProperty userprop JOIN userprop.property prop WHERE prop.id = '$propertyId'";
```

or

```
$queryUserId = "SELECT user FROM User user JOIN user.userProperties userprop WHERE userprop in(SELECT up FROM UserProperty up WHERE up.property = '$property')";
```

As of today i'm not able to get something sensible out of the system other then "Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression"...

Anyone can help?

Edit: I'll clarify what i'm trying to do here.

What i want is the DQL version of this sql query (which works):

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE id
IN (
     SELECT u.userId
     FROM userproperties u, properties p
     WHERE u.propertyID = p.id
     AND p.id =1
)
```

Where the p.id = xxx would be the property object (or at least the id) that i want to use in my search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok seems i have found a working DQL solution:

```
$query = "SELECT user from User user WHERE user.id in(SELECT u FROM UserProperty up JOIN up.user u WHERE up.property = '$property')"
```

Works! (You need to join on user in the subQuery else you get the dreaded "Invalid PathExpression" exception.